# why is my Discord bot deleting messages from other channnels and not adding values to the variable?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a game to my discord bot that people count numbers in a channel. I wrote a code and it worked properly but now it removes messages from any other channel and the number variable doesn't go up. Here's the code I wrote for that section:

```
    var number = 0;
    var nextnum = number+=1;
    Bot.on("message" , msg=> {
        let arg = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

        if(msg.channel.id===693689843141574737 && msg==number){
            number++;
        } else if (msg.channel.id===693689843141574737 && msg != number || msg != nextnum) {
            msg.delete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work. I'm first checking the channel and then the message.

```js
var number = 1;

Bot.on("message" , msg => {
  let arg = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
  if(msg.channel.id === "693689843141574737"){
    if(msg.content.trim() == number + ""){
      number++;
    }
    else{
      msg.delete();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: it still delete messages on every channel and doesn't even count up :v